# Cant Convert Clarifai response to Json

Tags: java, android, json, clarifai

I have just started using clarifai for image analysis but I can't actually convert the output I am getting as a List into Json.
The List is not the normal list, 
I have tried the normal Gson().toJson but not to any effect.
My request code is :

```
 final PredictRequest<Concept> predictionResults = client.getDefaultModels().generalModel().predict().withInputs(ClarifaiInput.forImage("image url here"));

        List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> result = predictionResults.executeSync().get();
        result.get(0);
```

Can anyone suggest something....

Answer (score 2):

Eddie from Clarifai here.

You can grab the raw JSON as a string using the `response.rawBody()` ([source](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-java/blob/a403d14427b96a4976be75e3b4dd00454363da5a/core/src/main/java/clarifai2/api/ClarifaiResponse.java#L129)) but should be able to get everything you need from the objects in the list. Is there something else that should be supported?